# Перемещение изображения по изображению

Tags: javascript, html5, анимация, изображения, canvas

Есть у меня изображение1 больше изображения2. Изображение2 каждую секунду перемещается по изображению1. Как реализовать это перемещение ? без нажатий клавиш клавиатуры,курсора.Буду рад если расскажете как это сделать....

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasId");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");



var images = new Image();
images.onload = function(){
ctx.drawImage(images,1,1,1050,1080);

}
images.src="https://wallbox.ru/wallpapers/main/201243/oboi-fon-41973d8.jpg";

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function(){
ctx.drawImage(image,100,100,250,180);

}
image.src="https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/11786028?s=400&amp;v=4";
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   
  
 <body>
  <center><canvas id="canvasId" width="1000" height="600" style="border:1px solid black;">
</canvas> </center>

 

 
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Приведите свой код

Comment: у меня нет кода

Comment: И чем мы тогда можем Вам помочь?

Comment: я описал чем мне надо помочь, помоги пожалуйста ! мне надо чтобы изображение перемещалось по иображению !!!! помоги мне....

Comment: Товарищ, от числа восклицательных знаков в Вашем сообщении скорость, с которой Вы получите помощь, **не увеличится**! А помочь Вам сейчас невозможно, ибо Вы попросту не расписали в вопросе, где находятся изображения и как оно должно перемещаться. Ибо механика с использованием, скажем `canvas` отлично от механики, которую следует применить в отношении тэга `img`. Дополните, пожалуйста, свой вопрос (следя за оформлением) и Вам обязательно помогут

Comment: И кроме того, если изображение передвигается само - нужно понимать закон перемещения во времени. В общем, вопрос нужно закрыть, так как нет ни кода, ни толком самого вопроса.

Comment: @AK, подождем лучше. Все таки новый участник, не знает, что тут да как. Может, дополнит)

Comment: я привел код, !!

Comment: Товарищ, ну уберите же Вы эти восклицательные знаки. И опишите, пожалуйста, какого именно «движения» Вы хотите достичь

Comment: простого движения, вправо или влево без клавиш клавиатуры,курсора просто движение и без стилей

Comment: @БогБогдан, для периодического вызова функции можно воспользоваться методами `setTimeout`, и `setInterval` - внутри которых менять положение нужной картинки

Comment: напишите код наконец-то я незнаю как это делаеться !